# Is there an easier way to open ports for the Media Center Extender?

Tags: windows-firewall, media-center-extender, xbox360

I'm trying to get the Xbox set up as a Media Center Extender and it's not helping that this computer's firewall is cranked up (Windows 7 Home Premium, by the way). I find that I have to open up a [whole list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911728) of processes to get the thing set up.

Surely there has to be an easier way to open up a range of ports?

Answer (score 3):

From MS' Media Center Extenders FAQ [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-Media-Center-Extenders-frequently-asked-questions):

> • If the only firewall running on your computer is Windows Firewall, make sure that the Media Center Extenders check box is selected in the Windows Firewall settings.

They provide further info at that link if you are still having troubles, or using a 3rd party firewall, etc.